# MySQL query to count the number of entries grouped by name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to do a simple query that will count the number of reviews for each company in a database table as follows grouped by name

e.g reviews table

```
id company_id review
1     1       Great
2     1       Ok
3     1       Bad
4     2       Nice
```

So this would return company id 1 with 3, and company id 2 with 1. Any ideas on the easiest solution

Comment: select company_id, count(review) from <table> group by company_id

Comment: Why `distinct review`? There might be more than 1 review of each type.

Comment: because I haven't woke up yet and I thought reviews were distinct.  Same reason I made it a comment and not an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select company_id, count(company_id) from tablename group by company_id
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT company_id,Count(1) FROM reviews GROUP BY company_Id;
```